# Is there any way to get the text of an element when DOM style="display:block; using selenium/js

Tags: javascript, java, html, selenium

I want to fetch the text of an element but using selenium methods, e.g `getText`, `getAttribute("textcontext")` it returns empty string.

```
<canvas class="tab canvas" width="247" height="91" style="display: block; position: absolute;">
```

Comment: Can you the code you have tried?

Comment: element.getAttribute("style") - use this method.

Comment: What do you expect for a text? The element has none.

Comment: I want the displayed text of that element on UI but by using selenium methods it's returning empty.